# Support multiple versions of an API simultaneously (via path)

Tags: openapi, loopbackjs, loopback4

Question: we've just started to explore loopback, one of our requirements is to host multiple versions of an API simultaneously (e.g. `foo.com/api/v1/products`, `foo.com/api/v2/products`).  Is this straightforward to do?  Any example(s) someone could point me at?  We've had problems trying to figure out how best to do this with OpenAPI in general (and other frameworks+OpenAPI)